# WebApi service down hosted on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, azure-web-app-service

I hosted a Web Api to azure app service. Everything works fine when I published it.

After a couple of days, the Web Api stops responding. But my app service is still running.
Even added application Insight Logs to all the code, to all the catch blocks, even then its not helpful.No exception was logged to date.

Checked the following, but doesn't seem to be helpful.

- Thread Count of app service.
- CPU time.

and this was the error when I tried to hit from postman after my web API is down.

```
<html><head><title>500 - The request timed out.</title></head><body>  <font color ="#aa0000"><h2>500 - The request timed out.</h2></font>  The web server failed to respond within the specified time.</body></html>
```

When I restarted my app service the web API started working and stops again after a couple of days.

Answer (score 0):

I think your app service is being idled out due to inactivity . Please set always on to be true in the general settings in configuration blade , you can check out link
[App service configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-common).